# MS Access Report Field Value as Heading with Other Field Values Beneath in Table

Tags: ms-access, report

In a Microsoft Access report, how can I display each record of a field as a column heading with the records of other fields in that columns records beneath it.

My query gives me data in the following format:

```
| ID |  Item  | Item Characteristic 1 | Item Characteristic 2 | Other Fields |
|:--:|:------:|:---------------------:|:---------------------:|--------------|
| 22 | Code 1 |          Blue         |           48          | …            |
| 22 | Code 2 |          Red          |           50          | …            |
| 22 | Code 3 |         Green         |           99          | …            |
```

I'd like to have on my report to look something like this:

```
|        Heading        | Data True to All Records1 | More Data True to All Records2 |              |
|:---------------------:|:-------------------------:|:------------------------------:|:------------:|
|      ------------     |        ------------       |          ------------          | ------------ |
|          Item         |           Code 1          |             Code 2             |    Code 3    |
| Item Characteristic 1 |            Blue           |               Red              |     Green    |
| Item Characteristic 2 |             48            |               50               |      99      |
|      Other Fields     |             …             |                …               |       …      |
|      ------------     |        ------------       |          ------------          | ------------ |
|         Footer        | Data True to All Records3 | More Data True to All Records4 |              |
```

Currently, I can only get data in the format:

```
| Heading |       |    |
|:-------:|:-----:|:--:|
|   ----  |       |    |
|  Code 1 |  Blue | 48 |
|         |       |    |
|  Code 2 |  Red  | 50 |
|         |       |    |
|  Code 3 | Green | 99 |
|   ---   |       |    |
|  Footer |       |    |
```

Where each record is resulting in a new 'row' in the report.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, I resolved this by setting out a table of unbound labels.

I gave each of these labels a control name of x-y, where x was the column number and y was the row number.

I then looped through each column and row and changed the caption of the label to the value from my RecordSet.

`(Form("FormName").Controls.Item(x & "-" & y)).Caption = .Fields("FieldName")`

Answer (score 0):

Table needs a unique record identifier - an autonumber type field should serve, then consider the following.

Query1:

```
SELECT RecID, ID, "Item" AS Category, Item AS Data FROM Tablename
UNION SELECT RecID, ID, "ItemChar1", ItemChar1 FROM Tablename
UNION SELECT RecID, ID, "ItemChar2", ItemChar2 FROM Tablename;
```

Query2:

```
TRANSFORM First(Query1.Data) AS FirstOfData
SELECT Query1.ID, Query1.Category
FROM Query1
GROUP BY Query1.ID, Query1.Category
PIVOT Query1.RecID;
```